# What is the size of background image with attachment: fixed; and size: cover;?

Tags: html, css

Precisely, if we have a block with its height more than a height of the viewport:

```
.foo {
  height: 110vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  ...
}
```

Is its background image with `attachment: fixed` and `size: cover;` going to take *the whole height of the* `.foo` *element* OR the *viewport*?

Comment: You know any way to see the size of background image in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just test it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqa0bxv4/)

It is clear that the inner .foo div extends beyond the body height. Note that even with body set to overflow: hidden, the .foo div appears to still go beyond the body tag.

I've also tested on the chrome device simulator by putting the body tag to 100vh and the image to 120vh, seen [image: here].

```css
body {
  height: 30vh;
}
.foo {
  background: url("http://orig15.deviantart.net/1c5c/f/2009/109/0/5/sample_background_5_by_hiagain69.jpg");
  height: 60vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the example. But still, if you set the .foo height to 110vh; and move its background-position by 10vh up, you will see the image repeating. Thus the viewport crops the background image: http://jsfiddle.net/vqa0bxv4/1/.

Comment: That's because your background-image is attached. no matter how large the image, that property will not allow scaling upwards of background images. What's the point of moving the background-position up 10vh?

Comment: I am trying to create a kind of a parallax background that changes the position of the background image as I scroll an element. Everything works OK except when the element height is more than that of the viewport. That's why I came to conclusion that bg image is actually the size of the viewport, not an element.

Comment: Take a look at this demo parallax scrolling with pure CSS: http://callmenick.com/_development/simple-parallax-effect/

If you update the class '.parallax-1' to a height of 200vh, the image **will** expand beyond the viewport.

Comment: Also want to mention that you didn't have 'no-repeat' for background-repeat. I'm not sure if i've answered your question based on my last comment above @Deka87?